# Conditions for cumulative distribution function

Tags: probability, functions, probability-distributions, density-function

What conditions must be satisfied by parameters $a,b\in \mathbb{R}$ if function $F:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ given by an equation:
$$F(t)=\begin{cases} 0 \ for \ t<1 \\ a+\frac{b}{t} \ for \ t\ge1 \end{cases}$$
is cumulative distribution function? What should be assumed to make this distribution continuous?
I know the definition of a cumulative distribution function, but i have no idea how to apply them in this case.

Comment: I think just $a=1$ and $-1\leq b\leq0$ will do

Comment: $F$ is continuous on $(-\infty,1)$ and on $(1,\infty)$. So the only thing needed for making it continuous on $\mathbb R$ is continuity at $1$.

Comment: I am not certain whether i fully understand why $-1\leq b\leq0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$F(t)$ must tend to $1$ as $t\to\infty$. This forces $a=1$. Also, $b$ cannot be positive, or else $F$ becomes a decreasing function. Finally, the value of $F(t)$ must be nonnegative for all $t$, which forces $b\ge -1$ (plug $t=1$).